# Is there any inequality that relates the norm of the determinant of the Hessian Matrix and the norm of the Laplacian in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\psi$ $\in H_0^2(\Omega)$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded, simply connected and smooth. Is there any inequality that relates the norm of the determinant of the Hessian Matrix and the norm of the Laplacian in $L^2(\Omega)$? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Integrating by parts twice (using the zero boundary condition) gives $\int |\Delta \psi|^2 = \int |\nabla^2 \psi|^2.$ From here you can estimate the determinant of the Hessian in terms of the norm of the Hessian and thus bound some $L^p$ norm of the determinant by the $L^2$ norm of the Laplacian. The exact exponent $p$ that works will depend on the dimension; but if you're willing to let the inequality depend on the size of the domain $\Omega$ you should be able to adjust it.

Comment: what do you mean by $\nabla^2 \psi$? is that the Hessian matrix?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's my notation for the Hessian.